# Passing more data @input angular 2

Tags: angular, input, two-way-binding

How can we switch more than one component to another component? I need to use the "two way data binding".

I tried the following way:

```
<app-drawer-menu [popup]="getPopupInstance" [appHeader]="getAppHeaderInstance"></app-drawer-menu>


 export class DrawerMenuComponent implements OnInit {


    @Input() private popup: DialogLoginSignupComponent;
    @Input() private appHeader: AppHeaderComponent;

    ....
```

I need to go to the "DrawerMenuComponent" component "DialogLoginSignupComponent" and "AppHeaderComponent"

this does not work. Where am I wrong?

thx!

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: what specific you want?

Comment: Inputs are meant to pass data to child components. Not instances of other components. That's all I can say, beause I agree with Maximus: it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so, You'll have to use a Service and pass the component class name to use to your child component. Then, use the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to create the component like this :

```
let factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
this.cmp = this.modalBody.createComponent(factory);
```

If you want more details, please looks the file modal.component.ts here : [Github link](https://github.com/MattewEon/ngx-heyl-modal/blob/master/lib/modal.component.ts)